# Process not waiting until get the data for api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

I am new to Nodejs. Process is not waiting until get the data from Mailgun api for mail validation.

Here is my code

```
var validator = require('mailgun-validate-email')('pubkey-xxxxxxxx')   
  validator(req.body.email, function (err, results)
  {
    console.log(results) // some times getting response. most of time getting undefind.
    if(results.is_valid == true )
    {
       User.findOne({ 'emails.email' : req.body.email}, function(err, doc){
          console.log(doc)
       })
    }
  })
```

Comment: We need to see more code context here to understand what your problem is.  What exactly is the problem and where does it occur in your code?  And, how is this code called and what data is it passed?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(err)` - it is possible that `results` are undefined because there was some kind of error.